# Login App wevbiew Exit Error (Back Button doesnt go to the dashboard and make works the custom exit)

Tags: android, authentication, webview, back

I have  made a webview apk in which we login first and then after authentication we see the dashboard
the problem is when i use the back button it directly shows the exit dialog box that i made instead of going back to the previous and i even tried to alter my code so what happens then, that the back button does go the previous page but it also directly logs me out of the profile after the dashboard page and when its on the login page the back button doesnt work the exit dialog box doesn't appear.

Please if someone can help me with this error .. here is the code for my back pressed button

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
    if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack() && webview==null) { 
        webview.goBack();
    }
    else {             
          new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
                .setTitle("EXIT")
                .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

I want when it reaches the dashboard it just asks for the exit dialog box when i press the back button twice that I created and then exit the app not directly the logged in id and doesnt got the login page directly.. I tried several times it doesnt work !

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the condition in the if statement to:

```
if (webview.canGoBack() && webview.getUrl() != "URL of the login page") {
    webview.goBack();
} else {
    ...
}
```

This will make the back button go back in the webview's history as long as the current URL is not the URL of the login page. When it reaches the login page, it will show the exit dialog.

Also, you have webview==null, this comparison will always return false and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks ! it works ...there's one catch as the values are string we wont be using "!=" instead we will use ` !Objects.equals(webview.getUrl(), " URL of the login page" )` ...also thanks for telling the webview ==null concept too